# Why is the state not being updated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

im trying to load images based on search query and able to drag them. For example when i type the word "Cat" i can see pictures of cats.
This is the code to type the search term:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.searchedValue} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({searchedValue: e.target.value})}}/>  
<button onClick={() => this.handlePress()}>Search</button>
```

This is the function to load image and put it in the array based on search query

```
 handlePress = async () => {
        console.log("function is called");
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/testData?title_picture=' + this.state.searchedValue, {
            "method": "GET"
        })
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseData) => {
             this.setState({newData: responseData,
                            loaded:true})
             console.log(this.state.newData);
         })
    }
```

this is to load the images

```
{this.state.newData.map((data) => (
                                            
                                            <div class="dragImg">
                                                
                                                  
                                                 <img src={data.picture} class="img"/> 
                                               
                                                
                                              </div>
                                         ))}
```

When i do the console log inside of `handlePress` function I can see there is a picture inside the array.
But when I do it in `ComponentDidMount()` it shows me an empty array. How can I solve this? It cannot be an empty array, otherwise I can't drag the picture to the canvas.

Comment: ComponentDidMount will call when your component loads first time in DOM and I think at first time your array will be blank. Do you see images after searching?

Comment: The images are shown. But the array is empty. To be able to be dragged in the div class="dragImg" it cannot be an empty array.

Comment: If images did show up then how can array be empty? you are showing images from data of array right?

Comment: Well the array is not empty in the Handlepress function. But it is empty in ComponentDidMount function. Because of that I cannot drag the picture.

Comment: The empty array in ComponentDidMount is expected since you are getting data through API call. If you cannot have an empty array, add some placeholder image to your state on the construction(){} of your component.

Answer (score 0):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

In your case, I do not see any reason to operate on the state instead on the response value in the "handlePress" method.
If you really need it, then you can use setState callback

```
this.setState({
  newData: responseData,
  loaded:true
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.newData)
})
```